# Are some infinite sequences longer than others?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In set theory, there are different levels of infinity and some infinite sets have more elements than other infinite sets.

Does similar concept exists in series and sequences? Namely, are some infinite sequences longer than others?

The followings are some examples I can think of:

1. The sequence of all non-negative integers and the sequence of all non-negative even numbers.

   - They probably have the same length as the underlaying sets are countable and there is no repeated element in either sequence.
2. The sequence of decimal expansion of $\pi$, $(3, 3.1, 3.14, \ldots)$ and the sequence of decimal digits of $\pi$, $(3, 1, 4, \ldots)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, every sequence is "equally long". A sequence is basically a map $$\mathbb N\to M$$ for some set $M$. This means that the "length" of a sequence always is the the cardinality of $\mathbb N$, $$|\mathbb N|=\aleph_0.$$

What you did in your $\pi$ examples was just to count things in different ways. This means that you found some bijection to $\mathbb N$ in both cases, which means that the two sequences are equally long.

Comment: ‘Eternity is very long time, especially towards the end’ (Woody Allen).